# Allow user to use Text input to create folder director and upload multiple images at the sametime

Tags: php, html, image, upload

How to Allow user to use **Text input to create folder director Name** and **upload multiple images** at the same-time.
I have use http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-upload-multiple-images-jquery-ajax-using-php_453.html and simple php code for creating director but i couldn't pass the folder folder director Name through ***jquery.fileuploadmulti.min*** or ***jquery.form***. Check my upload.php code below

```
require 'dbconnection.php';

//The name of the directory that we need to create.
$directoryName = $_POST['folder'];

//Check if the directory already exists.
if(!is_dir($directoryName)){
    //Directory does not exist, so lets create it.
     mkdir('imageFolder/'.$directoryName, 0755);
}
$output_dir = 'imageFolder/'.$directoryName.'/'; 

if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
    $ret = array();

    $error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
   {

        if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]['name'])) //single file
        {
            $RandomNum   = time();

            $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name']));
            $ImageType      = $_FILES['myfile']['type']; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

            $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
            $ImageExt       = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
            $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
            $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;
            $url = "$output_dir$NewImageName";

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $NewImageName);
             //echo "<br> Error: ".$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO pictures(picture,url,name,folder) VALUES('$NewImageName','$output_dir$NewImageName','','$output_dir')") or die(mysql_error());
                 $ret[$fileName]= $output_dir.$NewImageName;
        }
        else
        {
            $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]['name']);
            for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
            {
                $RandomNum   = time();

                $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]));
                $ImageType      = $_FILES['myfile']['type'][$i]; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

                $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
                $ImageExt       = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
                $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
                $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;

                $ret[$NewImageName]= $output_dir.$NewImageName;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$NewImageName );
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO pictures(picture,url,name,folder) VALUES('$NewImageName','$output_dir$NewImageName','','$output_dir')") or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($ret);

}
```

Comment: I want to pass folder name when user upload multiple images. so that uploaded images can belong to the folder name @SumanDey

Comment: My form contains only text field and file field. @SumanDey

Comment: one moment please

Comment: Anybody who can Help?

Comment: Taking too long @SumanDey